# How to make custom components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So bascially I want to change how the snackbar background, buttons and so on look.
I am new to material UI and I don't know if I am on the right path and this is what i am trying.

```
const styles = {
    root: {
      background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)'
  };

const CustomSnackbar = props => <Snackbar {...props} />;

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomSnackbar);
```

The problem is I don't know how to change the child components styles because the background color is set in the child. This is the same for other components. Any help will be apreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please include in your question an example with child components where you have had problems.

Answer (score 1):

I could try to explain but I think it's easier to give you this [link](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes)

just try adding `classes={{ root: props.classes.root }}` to your component

Answer (score 0):

You can override styles from `Snackbar` component, you can use this guide [Snackbar API](https://material-ui.com/api/snackbar/#css), so if you really want to change the button look and feels, as you can see your Snackbar allow you to pass a property called `actions`, so in there you should set your buttons already styled, please follow the [demo](https://material-ui.com/demos/snackbars/) for Snackbar components